# Get Url string parameter as JSON object

Tags: javascript, location, window

I was wondering if it is possible to get the url parameter as JSON object using window object.

For ex. I have the url "/#/health?firstName=tom&secondName=Mike"

and get the value as {"firstName": "tom", "secondName": "Mike"}

I tried to explore the window object but could not find any help.

I think I can try parsing the string firstName=tom&secondName=Mike and convert this to json but this doesn't look like a great approach. BTW if there are smart way to parse, that too will be appreciated.

Please let me know if I should provide any more information.

Comment: I am sorry for adding angular tag...here I am basically I am looking for a javascript implementation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular you can get the URL with:

```
this.router.url
```

Once you've got the URL, you should use the very popular (14 mill downloads a week) npm [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) module:

```
var qs = require('qs');
var obj = qs.parse('firstName=tom&secondName=Mike');
```

returns:

```
{
  firstName: 'tom'
  secondName: 'mike'
}
```

Comment: ^ This is a great suggestion! First you need to get the params from the URL though

Comment: Cool, I provided an answer with an optional function and then made reference to your answer for parsing. Is there a way to tag people or answers in an answer on here?

Answer (score 2):

Using straight javascript first get the params and then convert them into an object:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // params will be an object with key value pairs based on the url query string
    var params = paramsToObject();
    console.log(params);

    // Get the parameters by splitting the url at the ?
    function getParams() {
        var uri = window.location.toString();
        if (uri.indexOf("?") > 0) {
            var params = uri.substring(uri.indexOf("?") + 1, uri.length);
            return params;
        }
        return "";
    }

    // Split the string by & and then split each pair by = then return the object
    function paramsToObject() {
        var params = getParams().split("&");
        var obj = {};

        for (p in params) {
            var arr = params[p].split("=");
            obj[arr[0]] = arr[1];
        }

        return obj;
    }
</script>
```

**If using Angular:**
You can use the qs npm module suggested in the answer by [danday74](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1205871/danday74).

Answer (score 1):

```
const str = 'abc=foo&def=%5Bbar%5D&xyz=5'

    // reduce takes an array and reduces it into a single value
    const nameVal = str.split('&').reduce((prev, curr) => {
    // see output here in console for clarity:
    console.log('curr= ', curr, ' prev = ', prev)
    prev[decodeURIComponent(curr.split('=')[0])] = decodeURIComponent(curr.split('=')[1]);
    return prev;
}, {});

// invoke 
console.log(nameVal);
```

Comment: Please add a description to you code so that @kaounKaoun can understand and modify it if needed.